# 'This post is a community wiki' banner, but none of the answers are CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I just ended up on "[Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)" and noticed that at the top of the screen there is a banner that reads:

> **This post is a Community Wiki.** Edit existing answers to improve this post. It is not currently accepting new answers.

As I scrolled down after reading the question, I realized that the banner was lying: all of the answers on this question are attributed to individual authors and none of them are CW. What is going on? Is this some weird new form of community wiki where the answer's original author gets all the credit (or blame)?

(Tagging discussion because it is entirely possible I missed an announcement since the Meta 'hot' concept was removed.)

Comment: Have you clicked on the link it offers? It links to "locked posts" and this one is locked. Calling locked posts "Community Wiki" is a bit strange, but the explanation regarding new answers is correct there.

Comment: No I didn't click on the link because I know what a CW is. :-/ Yeah, it's definitely a locked post, but I'd still like to know why it's being called a CW now.

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341619/freeform-lock-reasons-would-be-useful) for a request to make the reasons more flexible: *There's a fixed, and rather small set of lock reasons*. I guess there wasn't any better option

Comment: A related bug filed about new post notices was marked as [meta-tag:status-bydesign]: [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337272)